# geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working when Cellular network is not available

Tags: javascript, geolocation, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a application and in this application i want to get getCurrentPosition.I have created a PWA app and also implemented offline mode.
So when internet is available , internet is not available in both cases it working fine but when cellular network in not available (Flight mode) then geolocation.getCurrentPosition function returning empty value.

Service Worker Code :-

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'geolocation_cache';
// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil( async function(){
    let cache= await caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
     await cache.addAll(
          [
            '/manifest.json',
            '/geolocationoffline.html',
          ]
        );
      }())
    });

 // Update or Activate a service worker
 self.addEventListener('activate', event =>{
  event.waitUntil( async function(){
    let cacheWhitelist = ['geolocation_cache'];
    let cacheNames = await caches.keys();
     await Promise.all(
      cacheNames.map(element => {
        if(cacheWhitelist.indexOf(element) === -1){
          return caches.delete(element);
        }
      })
     )
  }())
 });

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith( async function(){
    const availableCache= await caches.open('geolocation_cache');
    if(event.request.url.indexOf('/geolocation') < 0){
      const availableCache= await caches.open('geolocation_dynamic');
      try{
      const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
      const cachedResponse = await availableCache.match(event.request);
      if(cachedResponse) return cachedResponse;
      const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
      event.waitUntil(
        availableCache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone())
      );
      return networkResponse;
    }
    catch(err){
      const availableCache= await caches.open('geolocation_cache');
      let response=await availableCache.match('/geolocationoffline.html');
      return response;
    }
  }
  else{
      return await fetch(event.request);
  }
  }())
});
```

Offline Page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <h3>Geo Location Offline</h3>
      <p class="time-info"></p>
      <p class="page-info"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    document.getElementsByClassName("page-info")[0].innerText=`lat=${position.coords.latitude} long=${position.coords.longitude}`;
    document.getElementsByClassName("time-info")[0].innerText=`timeStamp=${position.timestamp}`;
  });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal.  Most devices also turn off GPS capability when in flight mode.

Comment: ok thanks. One of my team member is suggesting me to create the Native App and according to him in Native APP it will work fine but i searched on google also and i didn't find any article regarding this.

Comment: Perhaps in your native app, you could take it out of airplane mode to force enable the location services?  Maybe that's what he's getting at.  This would be an unusual and problem not desirable thing to do though.  All your user has to do is turn on location services themselves, after they've turned on airplane mode.  Also a normal thing to do.